# bib list print to a character string in R

Tags: r, bibtex

I'm reading a bib file extracted from Google Scholar with BIB <- bibtex::read.bib("file.bib") command and this created a list object. If I use paste(BIB) or as.character(BIB) the console shows for all items in the list lines like:

"list(title = "A Lealdade no Sistema Financeiro Portugu{\\^e}s", author = list(list(given = c("Francisco", "José", "dos", "Santos", "Mota", "Ferreira"), family = "Guerra", role = NULL, email = NULL, comment = NULL)), year = "2017", school = "Universidade de Coimbra")"

And if I use print() shows:

Guerra FJdSMF (2017). *A Lealdade no Sistema Financeiro Português*. Ph.D. thesis,
Universidade de Coimbra.

I need to extract the second kind to a new character string, but any command I try just doesn't work. I've tried A <- paste(print(BIB)), A <- as.character(print(BIB)) or just A <- print(BIB). I just get the first kind of line or an equal object.

I have already tried open the same file with bib2df::bib2df() but has some problems with the encoding and the dataframe's columns and rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `format(BIB)` For example

```
bib <- read.bib( package = "bibtex" )
x <- format(bib)
x
# [1] "R Development Core Team (2009). _R: A Language and Environment for\nStatistical Computing_. R Foundation for Statistical Computing, Vienna,\nAustria. ISBN 3-900051-07-0, <http://www.R-project.org>."
```

I found this by looking at `class(BIB)` and saw "bibentry" then looked for all methods that recognize that object `methods(class="bibentry")` and `format` seemed like a good candidate.